# Gomoku in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was playing around with the pygame module, and decided I should try to make a game. I like to play Gomoku, so that was the game I decided to make.

It is my first experience with pygame, thus I'm guessing there is plenty to improve on. Any stylistic review or more pygame specific would be helpfull.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


# Define some colors
BLACK  = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE  = (245, 245, 245)
RED    = (133, 42, 44)
YELLOW = (208, 176, 144)
GREEN  = (26, 81, 79)
PLAYER = False

# Define grid globals
WIDTH = 20
MARGIN = 1
PADDING = 20
DOT = 4
BOARD = (WIDTH + MARGIN) * 14 + MARGIN
GAME_WIDTH = BOARD + PADDING * 2
GAME_HIGHT = GAME_WIDTH + 100


class Gomoku:
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = [[0 for x in range(15)] for y in range(15)]
        pygame.init()
        pygame.font.init()
        self._display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode((GAME_WIDTH,GAME_HIGHT), pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

        pygame.display.set_caption('Gomoku')

        self._running = True
        self._playing = False
        self._win = False
        self.lastPosition = [-1,-1]

    def on_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self._running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            #does not update postion in python3.6, and I don't know why
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            global PLAYER
            if self.mouse_in_botton(pos):
                if not self._playing:
                    self.start()
                    if PLAYER:
                        PLAYER = not PLAYER
                else:
                    self.surrender()
                    PLAYER = not PLAYER

            elif self._playing:
                r = (pos[0] - PADDING + WIDTH // 2) // (WIDTH + MARGIN)
                c = (pos[1] - PADDING + WIDTH // 2) // (WIDTH + MARGIN)

                if 0 <= r < 15 and 0 <= c < 15:
                    if self.grid[r][c] == 0:
                        self.lastPosition = [r,c]
                        self.grid[r][c] = 1 if PLAYER else 2

                        # check win
                        if self.check_win([r,c],PLAYER):
                            self._win = True
                            self._playing = False
                        else:
                            PLAYER = not PLAYER



    def on_render(self):
        self.render_gomoku_piece()
        self.render_last_position()
        self.render_game_info()
        self.render_button()
        pygame.display.update()


    def on_cleanup(self):
        pygame.quit()


    def on_execute(self):   
        while( self._running ):
            self.gomoku_board_init()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                self.on_event(event)
            self.on_render()
        self.on_cleanup()


    def start(self):
        self._playing = True
        self.grid = [[0 for x in range(15)] for y in range(15)]
        self.lastPosition = [-1,-1]
        self._win = False


    def surrender(self):
        self._playing = False
        self._win = True


    def gomoku_board_init(self):
        self._display_surf.fill(YELLOW)
        # Draw background rect for game area
        pygame.draw.rect(self._display_surf, BLACK,
                         [PADDING,
                          PADDING,
                          BOARD,
                          BOARD]) 

        # Draw the grid
        for row in range(14):
            for column in range(14):
                pygame.draw.rect(self._display_surf, YELLOW,
                                 [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN + PADDING,
                                  (MARGIN + WIDTH) * row + MARGIN + PADDING,
                                  WIDTH,
                                  WIDTH])

        # Five dots
        points = [(3,3),(11,3),(3,11),(11,11),(7,7)]
        for point in points:
            pygame.draw.rect(self._display_surf, BLACK,
                            (PADDING + point[0] * (MARGIN + WIDTH) - DOT // 2,
                             PADDING + point[1] * (MARGIN + WIDTH) - DOT // 2,
                             DOT,
                             DOT),0)


    def mouse_in_botton(self,pos):
        if GAME_WIDTH // 2 - 50 <= pos[0] <= GAME_WIDTH // 2 + 50 and GAME_HIGHT - 50 <= pos[1] <= GAME_HIGHT - 20:
           return True
        return False


    def render_button(self):
        color = GREEN if not self._playing else RED
        info = "Start" if not self._playing else "Surrender"

        pygame.draw.rect(self._display_surf, color, 
                         (GAME_WIDTH // 2 - 50, GAME_HIGHT - 50, 100, 30))

        info_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Helvetica', 18)
        text = info_font.render(info, True, WHITE)
        textRect = text.get_rect()
        textRect.centerx = GAME_WIDTH // 2
        textRect.centery = GAME_HIGHT - 35
        self._display_surf.blit(text, textRect)


    def render_game_info(self):
        #current player color
        color = BLACK if not PLAYER else WHITE
        center = (GAME_WIDTH // 2 - 60, BOARD + 60)
        radius = 12
        pygame.draw.circle(self._display_surf, color, center, radius, 0)


        info = "You Win" if self._win else "Your Turn"
        info_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Helvetica', 24)
        text = info_font.render(info, True, BLACK)
        textRect = text.get_rect()
        textRect.centerx = self._display_surf.get_rect().centerx + 20
        textRect.centery = center[1]
        self._display_surf.blit(text, textRect)


    def render_gomoku_piece(self):
        for r in range(15):
            for c in range(15):
                center = ((MARGIN + WIDTH) * r + MARGIN + PADDING,
                          (MARGIN + WIDTH) * c + MARGIN + PADDING)
                if self.grid[r][c] > 0:

                    color = BLACK if self.grid[r][c] == 2 else WHITE
                    pygame.draw.circle(self._display_surf, color,
                                       center,
                                       WIDTH // 2 - MARGIN,0)


    def render_last_position(self):
        if self.lastPosition[0] > 0 and self.lastPosition[1] > 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(self._display_surf,RED,
                             ((MARGIN + WIDTH) * self.lastPosition[0] + (MARGIN + WIDTH) // 2, 
                              (MARGIN + WIDTH) * self.lastPosition[1] + (MARGIN + WIDTH) // 2, 
                              (MARGIN + WIDTH), 
                              (MARGIN + WIDTH)),1)


    def check_win(self,position,player):
        target = 1 if player else 2
        if self.grid[position[0]][position[1]] != target:
            return False
        directions = [([0,1] , [0,-1]) , ([1,0] , [-1,0]) , ([-1,1] , [1,-1]) , ([1,1] , [-1,-1])]
        for direction in directions:
            continue_chess = 0
            for i in range(2):
                p = position[:]
                while 0 <= p[0] < 15 and 0 <= p[1] < 15:
                    if self.grid[p[0]][p[1]] == target:
                        continue_chess += 1
                    else:
                        break
                    p[0] += direction[i][0]
                    p[1] += direction[i][1]
            if continue_chess >= 6:
                return True
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    gomoku = Gomoku()
    gomoku.on_execute()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall the code looks good to me. Here are few minor improvements you can do:

- Make the code [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compatible. Currently you will see decent number of issues if you run it on http://pep8online.com/.
- `[[0 for x in range(15)] for y in range(15)]` could be replaced with `[[0] * 15 for y in range(15)]`. This is fine as `0` is immutable but can be [an issue with mutable objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/unexpected-feature-in-a-python-list-of-lists).
- Instead of having a global variable `PLAYER` see if you can move it within the class as an instance variable.
- You have been doing nested loops at multiple places, you can replace them with `itertools.product`. This reduces an extra level of indentation and will probably be faster too as it removed one Python level for-loop.

  ```
  from itertools import product

  for row, column in product(range(14), repeat=2):
      ...
  ```
- I am not sure whether `from pygame.locals import *` is a [common practice in Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ImportInit.html) to import the constants, but usually `import *` is frowned upon because it introduces unknown variables in the current namespace. `import *` based imports can be helpful in shell for debugging and you may sometimes see them in a package's `__init__.py` to help define a [clean public API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#public-and-internal-interfaces).
- It's unclear whether you're using Python 2 or 3. If it's Python 2 then make sure your class inherits from object to make it a new-style class: `class Gomoku(object):`. Check: [New-style and classic classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).

Comment: Thank you for your review! I've updated my code with your improvements and made it PEP8 compatible which I should have done a long time ago...